# Can we rename dual-licensing to multi-licensing?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

It may not be common, but I'm raising this post to hear the community thoughts:

From the [dual-licensing](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dual-licensing) excerpt (emphasis mine):

> Works can be released under **two (or more) licenses**, which may or may not be compatible, giving recipients the choice of which terms they will abide by

I'm asking one thing: Should we make a [multi-licensing](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-licensing), and make [dual-licensing](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dual-licensing) a synonym?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically correct, but 'dual-licensing' is (I think) the commonly used term.

Answer (score 1):

We should *not* go ahead with this renaming.  "dual-licensing" is the commonly used term and the term "multi-licensing" should have mariginal or no use in the context of free software.

The tag excerpt cited by the OP is IMHO incomplete and somewhat misleading. In the *context of free software* "dual-licensing" is a much used *business-model* that is common enough to justify it having its own tag. The business model of dual-licensing means that in addition to a free software license, the software is also offered under a non-free commercial license (specifically for those who don't like copyleft). Since there are only two options - *free* and *non-free* - there is no real use case for more than two licenses.

"Multi-licensing", on the other hand, has not yet been used as a tag.  When I search for this term in questions, its use seems limited to questions showing poor understanding of licensing principles, or having only been posted in order to play "what-if" mind games about very *hypothetical* and *speculative* scenarios. I don't think this site benefits from this type of questions.  Instead we should encourage users to ask  good questions about *real* free software and free culture use cases.

Since "multi-licensing" is not currently a term, discouraging its use is not on the table, but for the record: I do not think "multi-licensing" *should* be term in the future, neither by renaming "dual-licensing", nor as an independent term.

Comment: But we're not talking about excerpts here. Also, excerpts can apply to multiple situations, I'm sure that dual-licensing is also a concept, not just a business model in that I can apply two or more licenses. Regardless, you don't seem to answer the question on whether you want to rename the tag and make one a synonym or anything like that.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Thanks for the down-vote! You *cite* the incomplete and wrong excerpt to indicate *why* the tag should be changed, so you're quite *explicitly* talking about the excerpt. I promise to delete this answer if you delete the quoted excerpt from your question.